# 0xE800003a Error when I try to install a second app onto my device

Tags: iphone

0xE8000003A Error:

I have developed AppOne for several weeks. I can debug on both the Simulator
and on the device.

I now want to develop a small test app, AppTwo , with a feature
which I later will port to AppOne. This involves text entry
into a TextView, so I definitely want to try AppTwo out on the device.

I can use the simulator fine, but each time I try to load AppTwo on the device
I get 
    0xE8000003A Error:
I clean all, I delete the build folder and still I get this error.

My Provisioning Profile (PP) that I have been using, used the following 
appID : 2QUXJRP5YK.com.CompanyName.AppName

I recently went to the portal and created a new PP hoping to solve this
program the new PP has
  appID : 2QUXJRP5YK.com.CompanyName.*

As I understand it, this PP will allow me to use the PP for
  any number of apps, not just the one named AppName

In Organizer I now have both of the PPs listed in the
  Provisioning Profile List Box. I believe this means both
  PPs are beening loaded onto the device.

I copied the Entitlements.plist from AppOne proj to AppTwo proj folder.

The Build Configuration Page 1, for Architecture through CodeSigning there
  are zero differences between AppOne and AppTwo.

Since AppTwo still works fine, it seems that I do not want to reset my
  device , but somehow tickle the Project  Config for AppTwo.

Do you have any advice for me, please?

Thanks very much, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last night I got the same error, and battled with it for a couple of hours.  I ended up creating the project from scratch again, crossed my fingers, and it synced  up.  Since its a simple test app, I would try and create a new dummy project that syncs, and then copy your code into it.  It doesn't take long to do and it may magically get things working for you.

Also, I believe that Entitlements.plist isn't needed until you start distributing.  In other words, you can install it on the device without it via XCode.

On another note, when I first started developing I got this error 100% of the time.  Sometimes due to a bad or dirty pin on my iPhone, it will lose its connection (which would happen when I would pick it up to test).  Now, I make sure that its connected in organizer.

Comment: Thanks Mike for replying. Good Answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes after adding entitltements/Bundle Identifier/provisioning for a new app, it's best to quit Xcode and relaunch.  This is the only way I can get Apple's samples to run without pulling my hair out.  I add the Bundle Identifier, I change the code signing settings in the Build Info window, quit and relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from user Rapzid at [the Unity Community:](http://forum.unity3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=23479&view=previous&sid=c849c67c624579bdc3983c4558d4cf7b)

In Xcode, right click on target and under the general(?) tab you will see a line about the developer or bundle identifier. You need to make sure that it's correct. If you restart xcode/unity/your iphone it might stop doing this. Otherwise you have to keep manually changing it everytime you build from unity.

Make sure your bundle identifier is set in unity. It's under edit->something->Player . Then in the right main pane you will see the bundle identifier line.

Also, if your not using a wild card for your app IDs you will need a new provisioning profile.